# Magento redirect to the page from that came

Tags: php, magento

I have a module which had instaled a CMS page with some default URL and some text with form. On this form I have fields and submit. I validate my fields using ajax(send POST in controller of my module). If validation is OK, I redirect to the same page with "succes message".

The problem is, that the default URL of this CMS page in which I make redirect after succes submit can be changed in BO - that's why I cannot just `$this->_redirect('default_URL')` in my controller, because this url can be changed.

What should I do?

**EDIT : Solution:** use $this->_redirectReferer() in my controller after success validation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put "back URL" to your form as a hidden field or you can use $this->_redirectReferer() to redirect back to CMS page.

See http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Core/Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.html#method_redirectReferer

If you want to redirect to some certain CMS page (not the one where form is placed) you can do this:

1. Add dropdown to system configuration to be able to select "Success page" (much better than hardcode cms page ID)
2. Redirect to this page in your controller

Code:

```
$pageId = Mage::getStoreConfig('mymodule/config/success_page');
$page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($pageId);
$this->_redirect($page->getUrlKey());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a store config by using the getStoreConfig method, something like

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('helloworld_options/messages/hello_message');
```

See [Alan's blog](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration), about detailed instructions how to create custom config values (which you might already have) and to access them.

Comment: Hmm, from this I see, that get a url from config, but it will a static or I need always change the value if someone go to BO->CMS page and select this page and change a url. But I want to have a dinamic. If some one (it will be administrator) change the value for this page in BO, in frony end after succes submit it redirect me at the same page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your comment right, but Mage::getStoreConfig IS reading that value dynamically from the database, whatever the administrator last time changed it to. Or do you mean something different?

Comment: I think Sergio means that URL configurable in the Backoffice > CMS > ..., not in System > Configuration.

Comment: So the url to the success page is defined inside another cms page?

Comment: See my answer here, it could be useful

Comment: No, it have to redirect to the same CMS page, but the url for this page can be changed by administrator. That's why I cannot just $this->_redirect('default_URL')

Comment: What about $this->_redirectReferer()?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for redirect to referer

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());?>
```

For example in custom login form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginPostUrl() ?>">
    <?php Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());?>
...
...
```